# Whoa there! There is no request token for this page

Tags: php, twitter

When i try to authenticate twitter using php am getting the error ' Whoa there!

There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake. '.

I have tried various code and still getting the error. how to resolve it ?

the following are my twitter auth links.

```
 protected $requestTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
  protected $accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token';
  protected $authorizeUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize';
  protected $apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/';
```

Please help.. 
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You might be using OAuth2, while Twitter uses OAuth

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me after I'd ticked 'Enable Callback Locking' in Application Settings.

Un-ticking it made the message go away :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got this when there was an issue with the url I used. If your url is wrong too you will get this error. At the time of writing this the url format is

`https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=authTokenHere`

Just mentioning this since this is also one of the causes. Your issue could be caused by something else too.